# Border wont show on click when using .addClass function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So i have a checklist where when clicked on next if all the checkboxes are not checked it needs to highlight/ give border to that checkbox button as red.
I created a css class with the name changeboxcolor but while i add it to that box the color wont change in inspect it shows that the class is added but the border wont show

This is my css

```css
.changeboxcolor{
    border-color: crimson;
}
```

This is the jquery

```
onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) { 
    if(newIndex === 1  && $(".check_list_1:checked").length !==  $(".check_list_1").length){ 
        $(".check_list_1").addClass("changeboxcolor");
        $(".check_list_1:checked").removeClass("changeboxcolor");    
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<td> 
    <span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="primary" style="border-color: crimson; width: 150px; height: 100px; white-space: normal;" style="width: 150px; height: 100px; white-space: normal;">Silicon and rear area clean</button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden check_list_1"/>
    </span>
</td>
```

so if i just add that class in that button es class="hidden check_list_1 changecolorbox" it does not work but if i add the border in style=border-color: crimson it works

Comment: In your conclusion, you write `changecolorbox`, but your code uses `changeboxcolor`. Is that just a typo, or have you actually been trying to add the wrong class?

Comment: its not i copy pasted class its just a typo here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it was adding the class to the `<checkbox>` while I needed to add the class to the button, so using the following fixed my problem:

```
$('input.check_list_1:checkbox:not(:checked)')
  .closest('span.button-checkbox')
  .find('button')
  .addClass('changeboxcolor');
```

Answer (score 3):

Only `border-color` is not enough to show border. `border-width` and `border-style` are still not set.

```
.changeboxcolor{
    border-color: crimson;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Or simpler would be setting all three in one line.

```
.changeboxcolor{
    border: 5px solid crimson;
}
```

Comment: @AhsanBaloch Then create a runnable snippet to show the problem.

Comment: imgur.com/a/3XGqkZd it is adding the class to the checkbox but it wont show. if i add the border-color in style in the div then it works but wont when a class is added

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a class to a class, you are not selecting an element in which to add the class to.

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").addClass("changeboxcolor")
```

The jQuery selector probably needs to be more selective as it'll search for any checkbox within the DOM and apply the class `changeboxcolor`.

Comment: as shown in the fig above it is adding the class to it but for some reason it wont give the border

Comment: I did notice that you have other classes applied to the input box, including one called hidden. If you go into Chrome developer tool bar and highlight the element in question, in the right hide side you'll see all of the styles applied to it (example https://imgur.com/a/su3h0o2 ). You may find that the border style is being overridden. Also in the same area, you can edit the CSS styling directly such that you can see what CSS is required without having to reload the page.

Answer (score -1):

Just changes this code

```
.changeboxcolor{
    border-color: crimson;
}
```

to

```
.changeboxcolor{
    border: 2px solid #FF0033;
}
```